# Custom fields do not show for AssociatedLocation

Tags: salesforcedx, custom-object, custom-field

I have split my metadata into multiple sub-directories (I'll call them 'tiers' here) with each properly described in my `sfdx-project.json`

I just successfully deployed 4 of the 5 tiers using `sfdx force:source:push --wait=90 -f`.

[image]

The fifth tier failed due to some dependencies on custom fields defined on the AssociatedLocation object (all my 'objects' are in the 4th tier, which as I said, deploys successfully to my shape-based scratch org)

When I go into my scratch org's Setup > Object Manager, I can see various custom fields I deployed on the Account object.. I can see completely new custom objects that I added into the org.. but why can't I see the custom fields that I added to my 'successfully deployed' AssociatedLocation object?

> Invalid field:AddressName__c in related list:AssociatedLocations

**One additional wrinkle:**
All the custom fields we added to AssociatedLocation are calculated - i.e. they have a formula. Not sure if that is important, but they do have this in common.

Answer (score 0):

OK - well.. answering my own question:

**These are the dumb things that happen when you forget to check .forceignore first**

Yes, a prior developer marked this object to be ignored. Thus, it merely had the appearance of a successful deployment.